# What do you call a network flow problem that allows negative flow values?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I'm trying to solve a relaxed network flow problem, where the relaxation discards the bounds constraints on the network flow (as opposed to a [pseudoflow](http://riot.ieor.berkeley.edu/Applications/Pseudoflow/maxflow.html), which discards the flow balance constraints).  In particular, this means that some flow values on arcs can be negative.  I'm aware that a negative flow on an arc is equivalent to a positive flow in the opposite direction, but for the purposes of my problem, I can't make such a transformation.

Is there any standard terminology for such a relaxation, or are there any problems or algorithms that make use of this type of relaxation?

Comment: Negative flow is just a flow the other way

Comment: Yes, I know.  From my question: "I'm aware that a negative flow on an arc is equivalent to a positive flow in the opposite direction, but for the purposes of my problem, I can't make such a transformation."

Comment: Then you can't have a negative flow.

Comment: Sure you can.  Forget the graph for a moment, consider the network LP.  Drop the bounds constraints so that the flow variables are unbounded.  Then your only constraint is that flow balance is satisfied at every vertex, and you can do this by pushing a positive amount of "flow" on a forward arc, or a negative amount of "flow" on the reverse arc.  It's no longer a valid network flow, in the same sense that a pseudoflow isn't a valid network flow, but it's still a valid mathematical construct.